# Excel Formulas to Use When Checking Criteria for a Column of Multiple Duplicate Values

Tags: excel

[Sample Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LcrBx.png)

I have a set of data in Microsoft Excel which contains a list of order numbers and a column confirming whether or not a job took place. I need to produce a formula in an additional column which identifies where the job completion = 'n', that I can flag this field with a comment such as in the attached screenshot in column AX, only if any other duplicates of the order number in column P are flagged with a Y (see rows 5 and 6 in the screenshot for reference).

Can anyone advise what the appropriate formula would be to get the desired result?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I feel as though this would be an easy fix with an If statement, example:

```
If(S2 = "Y","",If(S2 = "n","Check with customer?","Did this job take place?"))
```

Then drag this formula down for every row needed.

Comment: Unfortunately it's not that simple, Where there is an 'n' in column S I need the formula to reference the ID in column P and where there are any duplicate IDs, then check those against column S to see if any say 'Y' and if they do, I need the formula to highlight the row with an 'N' for further investigation. There are circumstances where all rows with the same ID in column P will have 'n' in column S, in that circumstance it can be disregarded.

Comment: Oh I see now, sorry I didn't quite understand the reference back to your Column P.